# Why is $pshome in a "v1.0" directory?

Tags: powershell

I'm clearly running powershell v2.0.x on Windows 7.

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.5444
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

So why is $pshome pointing to a directory named v1.0?

```
PS C:\> $pshome
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Should I just file this under "Business as usual" for microsoft? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for backwards compatability.  V1 scripts should run with little or no changes.  Until there are major changes to the version of .NET that PowerShell is built against, the plan seems to be to stick with "1".

Notice the extension is still .ps1 as well

Comment: "Major" is usually characterized by a X.0 shift. :-)
Oh well...

Comment: powershell 2.0 is a major version of powershell but the framework is still the same

Comment: `c:\windows\system32` on a 64 bit system, same thing.  Windows 7's version number is really `6.1.xxxx`, same thing.  Microsoft doesn't really care about what's intuitive.

Comment: They care less about being intuitive, and more about not pissing off enterprise users that have hard-coded/made assumptions.

Comment: @shane Madden - and for more non-intuitiveness the 32 bit root on a 64bit system is syswow64...

Comment: @riknik Exactly!  They're so terrified of breaking someone's junky, ancient application that Windows 7 has a drop-down option to put programs in Windows 95 compatibility mode.  And contains the 16-bit DOS compatibility layer that cropped up a [major vulnerability after 17 years](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/Bulletin/MS10-015.mspx).  Massive inherent security issues like [dynamic DLL loading](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/advisory/2269637.mspx) will never be fixed, because they're too obsessed with never breaking an old application.  And don't get me started on IE6 ;)

Comment: @Shane Madden - I didn't say it was necessarily a bad thing. :) It's why companies will build million and billion dollar businesses on MSFT technologies... Bad comes with the good.

Comment: @riknik Just pointing out that their fanatical devotion to backwards compatibility has real negative consequences in security and stability - the names are just a more harmless example of that philosophy.  It'll be an interesting day when they finally need to get rid of all the compatibility layers and make a clean break.

Answer (score 0):

If it really bothers you, or if you want to move the location.

Copy the Directory to the version and or location you want it to be, then create a symbolic link to that directory called v1.0

```
mklink /d "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" "D:\Location\You\Want\It\To\Be\v2.2"
```